# How to add evolution contacts to libreoffice in vivid (possibly libreoffice-evolution issue)

Tags: libreoffice, evolution, contacts

I found several tutorials to achieve this, however there is no option to add an evolution address book in LibreOffice on my installation, neither with stock LibreOffice nor with the updated one (LibreOffice PPA). It only shows Firefox/Icewheezle Thunderbird/Icedove and others.

I tried installing `libreoffice-evolution` but there is no release candidate available and it seems there is no amd64 version for Vivid.

I tried to find a solution on the internet but it seems people either don't have this problem or no one cares about it.

Edit: I tried exporting evolution contacts to thunderbird (inconvenient) but that doesn't work either, I lose about half the information (all numbers are missing).

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It is really annoying that Ubuntu does not ship LibreOffice with **libreoffice-evolution** support. I hope they will fix this [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libreoffice/+bug/1353051).

There is a workaround and the credit goes to NoOp:
You have to install the **non-Ubuntu LibreOffice (LO)** from the [main download page](https://www.libreoffice.org/download/) or the [archive](http://downloadarchive.documentfoundation.org/libreoffice/old/) along to the Ubuntu-LO (no need to uninstall the default Ubuntu-LO):

1. Download the .deb versions of LO (include the help file .deb):  https://www.libreoffice.org/download/
   Download the DEB-version. If it is not the correct one, choose “change?” Change System, Version or Language". Pick your architecture (32 bit or 64 bit): "Linux (deb): x86 or x86_64". I'll use 32bit for this explanation, but the procedure for 64bit is the same.
   Note: I will use US English, but you can use any other language.
   Download both Main Installer and Help.
2. Extract the .tar.gz files. Easiest way is to open Nautilus, right click on the .tar.gz and select "Extract here". That will extract the files to their own folders (with the correct permissions):
3. Open gnome-terminal and cd to the /DEB folder:

   ```
   cd /home/<path?/LibreOffice_4.4.5.1_Linux_x86_deb/DEBS
   ```

   (remember I'm using 32bit & US english as an example)
   Mine is located here, so I'll use that as an example: `/home/gg/tempdir/LibreOffice_4.4.5.1_Linux_x86_deb/DEBS/`
4. Now install LO. Note: this will install LO in the `/opt` directory, and will have no affect on your Ubuntu installation.

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i *.deb
   ```
5. Now do the same for the help files:

   ```
   cd /home/<path>/LibreOffice_4.4.5.1_Linux_x86_deb_helppack_en-US/DEBS  

   sudo dpkg -i *.deb
   ```
6. Now modify the bootstrap destination so that your standard LO doesn't affect your Ubuntu LO install:

   ```
   gksu gedit /opt/libreoffice4.4/program/bootstraprc
   ```

   Change this line:

   ```
   UserInstallation=$SYSUSERCONFIG/libreoffice/4
   ```

   to

   ```
   UserInstallation=$SYSUSERCONFIG/libreoffice4.4/4
   ```

   File|Save|Quit
7. The Ubuntu LO user profile gets installed to: `/home/<user>/.config/libreoffice`
   So we put the 4.4 standard profile here instead (create a new folder with the folder name libreoffice4.4):
   `/home/<user>/.config/libreoffice4.4`
8. Now start standard LO to ensure all is working:

   ```
    /opt/libreoffice4.4/program/soffice
   ```

   Make sure it's working. Also check to see if your Address data sources are working: Database|Connect to an existing database|check to see if you have Evolution, Thunderbird etc.
   While it is up and open, open the Ubuntu LO to ensure that you can run both in parallel/side-by-side. If all is working OK for you, create a menu item/icon so that you can use the standard LO.

To **uninstall** the non-Ubuntu LO you can use **Synaptic**:
- search for libobasis[version number] and mark all for complete removal
(it will also pull in and mark libreoffice[version]. And then apply.

or from the command line:

```
sudo apt-get -s purge libobasis[version number]
```

example if you have version 4.4 installed:

```
sudo apt-get -s purge libobasis4.4 libreoffice4.4
```

Note: use the '-s' option to 'simulate' the purge first, and if satisfied that all is well, remove the '-s' and purge:

```
sudo apt-get purge libobasis4.4 libreoffice4.4
```

now remove the left over /opt directory:

```
sudo rm -R /opt/libreoffice4.4
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use your address book Evolution in LibreOffice as data sources.

If this is what you want to do.

1. In the menu bar click --- `Edit`--- `Exchange database`

   *(This will display the box Exchanging data base dialogue)*
2. In the right pane, under `Databases available`, `EvolutionLocal` is available as a source. Click the small triangle to get a list of your address books of Evolution.
3. Select an address book and click `Define`
4. You should not list click `Browse`

   *(One file selection dialog opens.)*
5. Since Evolution stores its data in a hidden folder, press Ctrl + L to display the address bar.
6. Go to `~/.local/share/evolution/addressbook/system/addressbook.db` and click `Open`.

   *(This makes the Evolution address book is the default data source LibreOffice.)*
7. You can select a field to insert into a document through LibreOffice `Insert` --- `Fields` --- `Other`.

Comment: that is exactly what I want to do... and what the tutorial says but in "Databases Available" there is no EvolutionLocal, only Firefox/Icewheezle Thunderbird/Icedove and others.

Comment: Short Addition - There is no ~/.local/share/evolution/addressbook/system/addressbook.db only contacts.db in this folder - I can choose that one but libreoffice doesn't know how to handle it.

Comment: And Another Addition - SFLphone does work with the evolution contacts database without problems - the problem seems to be on the LO side rather than the evolution side.

Answer (score 0):

It seems it indeed is not possible(!) to import evolution contacts in LibreOffice, since the package `libreoffice-evolution` was deleted from PPA a while ago.

This [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libreoffice/+bug/1353051) is about 14.04. but is the same thing I experienced. It confirmed but never got fixed.

I couldn't figure out why it was removed, nor whether there is a new version and how to get it... which means that at the moment it is not possible.

Which is kind of sad since a) many other apps rely on evolution-server so I have to use it anyway and b) the carddav plugin for thunderbird always messes up my contacts on my mobile - which makes syncing these impossible.